# Docker compose a MERN app with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, docker

I  have created a MERN app with MongoDB Atlas such that node runs on port 3000 and react runs on 3001 and connected the node end points to react.

[image]

the Docker file for react is

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and for nodeJS is

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

now the compose file is

```
services:
  react-app:
    image: react-app
    build: ./client
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    networks:
      - mern-app

  node-web-api:
    image: node-web-api
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - mern-app

networks:
  mern-app:
    driver: bridge
```

**now when i am composing it everything is workfine it composing sucessfully but the react is running on port 3000 instead of 3001**
**how can i fix this issue??**

Answer (score 0):

npm default port is 3000, so if you want to run in on another port you should change the command to:

```
npm start --port 3001
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to have multiple processes running in containers listening on the same port.  The Docker-level settings you show in the question have no effect on whatever `listen()` call is in the application.  ([@MojtabaAhadi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71778927) discusses setting Node to listen on a different port.)

What you can do instead is set the application to listen on its normal port, but remap that in the Compose setup.  In the Dockerfile, change:

```sh
EXPOSE 3000
```

to match the port the application actually listens on.  (Or not, or delete this line entirely; it doesn't actually do anything in modern Docker.)

In the Compose file, for that container, the second `ports:` number needs to match what the application is listening on, and the first number is a host port that isn't otherwise in use.  They don't need to be the same.

```yaml
ports:
  - '3001:3000'
```

If host port 3001 is busy then you can change that first port number only without rebuilding your image or changing anything else in the container setup.

Comment: Made the changes in the compose.yml file for react and it changes from 3001-3000 and it's working on port 3001 but throwing cors related error.

 (Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.)